# Declarative jenkins pipeline, retrieve artifact

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently trying to trigger an existing job and take in the generated
artifacts in the current job's workspace.

The following works fine:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'builder-rpm'
    }

    options {
        timestamps()
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build Other pipeline') {
            steps {
                build job: 'Components/components-rpm-build', parameters: [
                    string(name: 'Component', value: 'foo'),
                ]
                copyArtifacts(
                    filter: 'results/*.rpm',
                    fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    projectName: 'Components/components-rpm-build',
                    selector: lastSuccessful(),
                    target: "${env.WORKSPACE}/dist"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem of it is that `lastSuccessful()` will take indeed the last
successful build, meaning that if some other user manages to run a parallel
build faster than me, I'm going to take in their artifacts instead of mine.

According to [this page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)
there should be a way to use a specific job, with `specific`:

```groovy
def built = build('downstream');
copyArtifacts(projectName: 'downstream',
              selector: specific("${downstream.number}"));
```

There's however no explanation nor example on how to use it in a declarative
pipeline.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some decent solution: switching to `script` simply does the job.

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'builder-rpm'
    }

    options {
        timestamps()
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build Other pipeline') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def built = build(
                        job:'Components/components-rpm-build',
                        parameters:[
                            string(name:'Component', value:'ew-filesystem'),
                            string(name:'RepoServer', value:'')
                        ]
                    )
                    copyArtifacts(
                        projectName: 'Components/components-rpm-build',
                        selector: specific("${built.number}"),
                        target: "${env.WORKSPACE}/dist",
                        filter: "results/*"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```